# Time Series Regression when X are not i.i.d

Tags: regression, time-series, t-test, autocorrelation

Suppose we have two time series $x_t$ and $y_t$ and both are i.i.d. The content of $y_t$ and $x_t$ do not matter. We can think these two are just two random time series. However, we run the following regression

\begin{align*}
y_t = a + b z_t, z_t = x_t + x_{t-1 } + x_{t-2} + x_{t-3} + x_{t-4}.
\end{align*}

The questions are whether the t-statistics of $\hat{b}$ is correct and if not how do we adjust without re-running the regression.

My intuition is that $z_t$ are not i.i.d across time. So this may introduce serial correlation which causes a larger t-stats. In order to adjust, we need to think about the correlation between $z_t$ and $z_{t-1}$. However, I am not sure how to derive this.

Comment: Please clarify: (1) what are the "$x_t$"? (2) To which "t-statistics" do you refer?  (3) What are you estimating?

Comment: Re the edit: although the $z_t$ are not iid, this is irrelevant.  All that matters concerns the distribution of the *error terms* in the regression.  Thus, you don't have to derive anything, unless those error terms are not independent.  What are you assuming about them?